# Lambda expression tree for related entities

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda, navigation-properties

Looking to create a kind of generic query builder where I have related entities via navigation properties. So I want to be able to say something like:

```
var results = from entityA in context.entityAs  
where entityA.NavigationPropertyB.PropertyZ = value1  
group entityA by entityA.NavigationPropertyC.PropertyY into g  
select new { propertyY = g.Key, value = g.OperatorD(x=>x.PropertyX)}
```

Where the entityA, related properties and operator can be provided on the fly. I was thinking of getting a collection of the properties for the given entity type and using them to build a lambda expression tree of the dynamic query.

a) Does that work? Is it sensible?

b) Is there an easy way of getting a single collection of all the properties I'd want to query on, including properties on related entities n number of relationships away from entityA?

c) What does a query tree look like for including related entities that are passed in at runtime?

Comment: I would definitely start with the Dynamic Linq. The advantage is that is is already implemented. Queries are passed as strings so your dynamic where clause would be `.Where( "NavigationProperty.PropertyZ=\"value1\"" )`.

Answer (score 0):

well, i have done something similar.

I've used LINQ Expressions (System.Linq.Expressions namespace), and i've created small parser also.

It took me some time but i am extremely happy with it, it's a beating heart for the whole application, so yeah, it works, and it is sensible.

To answer b):
whatever you can write in code in VS editor, you can create (express) via LINQ Expressions, because that's what compiler anyway does. Some methods are easier like Where() or Count(), some harder like Join() or your GroupBy(), but at the end of the day, it can all be done.

c)
No matter whether you write your query statically, or you construct it dynamically at runtime, expression tree will look the same, it only gets evaluated when materializing.

Here's an example:

```
string query = "db.Documents.Count() != 0 ? db.Documents.Where(d => d.No == 176).Items.Select(a => a.Debit).Sum() : 0";
var result = ExprBuilder.DoExpression(new MyDbContext(), query);
```

So basically, it's not very easy, it may not be worth the time (depends how much you need it), but it can be done and can come very handy.